# Integral of spherical Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: integration

I need to calculate an integral including the bessel function of the first kind $$j_0(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}x $$
but i cant figure out how to solve this:

$$\int_\Omega v^T(p) v(p) dp$$

where

$$v=[j_0(w||p-p_1||),...,j_0(w||p-p_M||)]$$

where $$p_1,...,p_M=(x,y,z)$$ is a set of points in the three dimensional domain.
How do I calculate this? :(

---

Edit: @AHusain so for M=1 it should look like this

$$\int_\Omega \frac{\sin(w||p-p_1||)}{w||p-p_1||}\frac{\sin(w||p-p_1||)}{w||p-p_1||}   dp$$

If M is not 1, then each entry must be integrated in the resulting matrix and placed in the new matrix afaik? I dont understand how to solve the entries containing this triple integral now. Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do for M=1 first.

Comment: I cant. I dont understand how to solve the triple integral.

Comment: Also to clarify, is $\Omega$ all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes. My physical interpretation is that $\Omega$ is an arbitrary domain in three dimensional space.

Comment: Being arbitrary domain means you will have little hope of getting a closed form solution. You will have to settle for lower, upper bounds or numeric approximation.

Comment: Thats sad. Alright - I guess a numeric approximation will have to be sufficient then. Thank you!